# How to compare two different Capture rates along the years?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, chi-squared-test

I have data on two capture rates for 13 consecutive years. I know that both rates increase along the years. But what I want to know if the two rates differ between them in each year.

Should I do an independent tests for each year? Or is there a way to compare all with a single test?

Thank you!

Comment: You have two rates A and B. For each year consider (A,B) pair of rates. See if there is significant correlation between A and B. Make a plot of A vs B. Can you see association in the plot (B increases as A increases)? If so, look at Pearson correlation. If not near 0, is it significantly different from 0? (Also, Spearman correlation if there seems to be correlation, but more curved than linear.)

Comment: The coefficient for Pearson correlation is 0.64 and the rho of Spearman correlation is 0.67. They don't seem to have a high correlation between them, what does this mean?

Comment: If you were trying to predict next year's capture rate for B, knowing next year's capture rate for A, you would likely do better than just by guessing (say, just by taking the 13-year average rate for B). You could use a regression approach for that. // If capture rates tells you about something else important, then knowing just A might work well, but also knowing B in addition to A might work a little better.